# How to loop through the children of a div nested three levels down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a structure that looks like this,

```js
$('#container').children().each(function() {
        var child = $(this).first();
        child.children().each(function() {
            console.log($(this).text() + '\nThis Should appear after each selectMe.text()');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
        <div class='firstRows'>
            <div class='childOfFirstRow'>
                <div class='selectMe'>
                    First set of data
                </div>
                <div class='selectMe'>
                    Second set of data
                </div>
                <div class='selectMe'>
                    Third set of data
                </div>
                <div class='selectMe'>
                    Fourth set of data
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='firstRows'>
            <!-- Same data inside me too -->
        </div>
        <div class='firstRows'>
            <!-- Same data inside me too -->
        </div>
        <div class='firstRows'> 
            <!-- Same data inside me too -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is what I have to do.

1. Loop through all the `firstRows` inside the `container`
2. For every row inside the `container`, go one element down to`childOfFirstRow`
3. For every `selectMe` inside of `childOfFirstRow`, change the data.

What I'm having trouble with is selecting `selectMe`. For some reason if I try this out,

```
$('#container').children().each(function() {
    $(this).first().children().each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

This will bring back all the children at once. Like I'm doing a `$(.childOfFirstRow).text();`

How would I get the `text()` of the `selectMe`'s one at a time, instead of all at once?

Comment: You need to explain what it is that you're trying to do, what do you mean by "*[getting] the [text] of the `selectMe`s one at a time*"?

Comment: @DavidThomas I mean.. Get the text of each `selectMe`.. one `selectMe` at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the **children of the children** in the container div:

```
$('#container').children().each(function() {
    $(this).first().children().children().each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zsnkcLs3/)

Comment: This is a simple to follow (In my own opinion) answer that worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, just use the selectors:

```js
$('#container .firstRows .childOfFirstRow .selectMe').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <div class='firstRows'>
    <div class='childOfFirstRow'>
      <div class='selectMe'>
        First set of data
      </div>
      <div class='selectMe'>
        Second set of data
      </div>
      <div class='selectMe'>
        Third set of data
      </div>
      <div class='selectMe'>
        Fourth set of data
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='firstRows'>
    <!-- Same data inside me too -->
  </div>
  <div class='firstRows'>
    <!-- Same data inside me too -->
  </div>
  <div class='firstRows'>
    <!-- Same data inside me too -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You lose the relationship of the `selectMe` divs to their parents unless you resort to DOM navigation at some point.

Comment: It's inferred from the OP's question:  "How to loop through the children of a div nested three levels down".  You're not showing how to loop through the **children** of a div.

Comment: @devlin You misunderstood. See the third point: "3. For every selectMe inside of childOfFirstRow, change the data".

Comment: You don't have **children** of `childOfFirstRow`.  You have any element that has `selectMe` as the class, regardless of whether it's a child of `childOfFirstRow` or not.  Like I said before, you lose the relationship of the `selectMe` to its parent with your approach.

Comment: @devlin OP doesn't need anything else than getting / changing the value of every `.selectMe`. Right? Then I don't see your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) like this:

```
$('#container').children().each(function(){     
    // more code here...
    $(this).find(".selectMe").each(function(){  // Here, $(this) is a "firstRows" element.
        console.log($(this).text());            // Here, $(this) is a "selectMe" element.
        // more code here...
    });
    // more code here...
});
```

It will litterally "find" all elements with class `selectMe` in all decendants levels of each childrens of `#container`.

---

I suppose that the idea is to apply different treatment to each `selectMe` "group" based on "of which" `firstRows` it is a decendant...
Because if not, this is more simple:

```
$('#container').find(".selectMe").each(function(){
    // Do something
    console.log($(this).text());    // Here, $(this) is a "selectMe" element.
});
```

**Here is an example snippet to show it:**

```js
$('#container').children().each(function(i,val){
 var j = i+1;
 console.log("firstRows id: "+$(this).attr("id"));
 // more code here...
 $(this).find(".selectMe").each(function(i,val){  // Here, $(this) is a "firstRows" element.
  var k=i+1;
  console.log($(this).text()+" - Original");            // Here, $(this) is a "selectMe" element.
  $(this).html("This element "+k+" of the firstRows "+j+" has changed!!!");
  console.log($(this).text());
  // more code here...
 });
 // more code here...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id='container'>
   <div class='firstRows' id="one">
  <div class='childOfFirstRow'>
    <div class='selectMe'>
   First set of data
    </div>
    <div class='selectMe'>
   Second set of data
    </div>
    <div class='selectMe'>
   Third set of data
    </div>
    <div class='selectMe'>
   Fourth set of data
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class='firstRows' id="Two">
  <div class='childOfFirstRow'>
    <div class='selectMe'>
   First set of data
    </div>
    <div class='selectMe'>
   Second set of data
    </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class='firstRows' id="Three">
  <!-- Same data inside me too -->
   </div>
   <div class='firstRows' id="Four">
  <!-- Same data inside me too -->
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain JS, not need for even jQuery. Plus it makes the logic easier IMO.

```
var firstRows = document.querySelectorAll("div.firstRows");
for(var i = 0; i < firstRows.length; i++){
  var children = firstRows[i].children[0].children;
  //children[0] is the "childOfFirstRow" div so calling children on that is the list of all the divs under it
  for(var j = 0; j < children.length; j++){
    //optional if check here to see if children[i].getAttribute('class') === "selectMe" if that is not a sure thing
    children[i].innerHTML="Whatever you need to change it to";
  }
}
```

This assumes that this nesting and the order is important. Otherwise just use this code:

```
var children = document.querySelectorAll('div.selectMe');
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
  children[i].innterHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also interact each level separately:

```
$('#container .firstRows').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.childOfFirstRow').each(function() {
       $(this).find('.selectMe').each(function() {
          console.log($(this).text());
       });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4w40of1w/)